# JavaScript: DOM manipulation and after that a search over all elements

Tags: javascript

I'm going to load several new elements (via AJAX) into the DOM. After that I want to "refresh" the document variable to select existing and new elements.

I tried to simplify my question with this small example:

```
// Creating a new element and insert it into DOM
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.style.color = 'red';
newdiv.innerHTML = 'this is a new div container';
newdiv.classList = 'newdiv';
document.getElementById('existingdiv').appendChild(newdiv);

// Search the complete DOM for the new element and try to select it (but abc is null)
var abc = document.querySelector('newdiv');
abc.style.color = 'blue';
```

Any ideas (without jQuery)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After that I want to "refresh" the document variable to select existing and new elements.

There's no need, `document` is **live**.

`querySelector('newdiv')` looks for an element with the **tag name** `newdiv`. You probably meant `querySelector('.newdiv')`, which looks for the first element with that class in the DOM.

Live Example:

```js
// Creating a new element and insert it into DOM
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.style.color = 'red';
newdiv.innerHTML = 'this is a new div container';
newdiv.classList = 'newdiv';
document.getElementById('existingdiv').appendChild(newdiv);

// Search the complete DOM for the new element and try to select it (but abc is null)
var abc = document.querySelector('.newdiv');
abc.style.color = 'blue';
```

```html
<div id="existingdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thx - sorry, seems that I'm blind!

Answer (score 3):

`newdiv` is a class not an element. To target that you have to specify dot (`.`) along with class name in the selector:

```
var abc = document.querySelector('.newdiv');
```